# Generic Interface<T> as constructor parameter for any derived T

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Effectively, I don't much care about the derived endpoints here. Everything I need is base. I just want to to be able to pass in any IClient, and use its method, regardless of what the derived endpoint is.

Disclaimer: Its very possible that in my effort to remove the extra stuff, I simplified this into not exactly the same thing.

I have the following constructor

```
  public SomeClass(????? client)
  {
      _client = client;
  }

  public SomeMethod<TEndPoint>(SpecialObject o, TEndPoint e)
    where TEndPoint: Endpoint
  {
      Validate(o);
      //Do OtherStuff
      _client.UploadToClient(o, e)
  }
```

The interface is as follows

```
  public interface IClient<TEndpoint> where TEndpoint: Endpoint
  {
      TEndpoint UploadToClient(obj o, endpoint e)
  }
```

And I have a few implementations

```
public class Client1: IClient<Endpoint1>
public class Client2: IClient<Endpoint2>
```

Are there any patterns/examples to get me to a point of being able to use a generic interface as a parameter without specifying a specific type?

---

Adding on,  I can design around some things, Really the main goal is that I just Don't want to make SomeCase generic, but do want to be able to cleanly and dynamically accept anything that implements IClient<>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how this could possibly work.  There would be no way to stop this from happening.

```
SomeClass myInstance = new SomeClass(new Client1());
Endpoint2 e2 = new Endpoint2();
myInstance.SomeMethod<Endpoint2>(o, e2);
```

Note that `myInstance` can only handle `Endpoint1` because of its construction, but it allows me to call SomeMethod using `Endpoint2`, even though the client will fail.  If you're willing to give up on static type safety, you can just declare everything `dynamic` and call it a day.

Comment: I definitely see the problem you are describing. I left in the wrong amount of detail. Im going to slightly modify the question because you are correct. Yet, Im not actually closer to the solution since i do want some type safety.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to have the kind of type safety you want, while keeping only a single non-generic `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your interface can be modified. Would the following not solve your problem?

```
public interface IClient
{
    void UploadToClient<TEnd>(obj o, TEnd endpoint) where TEnd: Endpoint;
}
```

Comment: I can, but the implementations actually in some instances do need the original implementation.. That would push the redesign down the road.